# Jacobi Plane rotation for a matrix A

Tags: matlab, matrix, decomposition

How to perform the Jacobi Rotation (Jacobi Methods) for given matrix `J(p,q,theta)`

There exists a rotation (c = cos(theta) and s = sin(theta))

```
[c  s
 -s c]
```

For example how can we estimate rotation for the following matrix

```
A = [-17.7147 -38.4117  30.6475
 -51.3024  17.3859 -10.0354
 -19.3323 -38.8931  30.3686
 -51.2891  18.9043 -11.1523
 -21.42 -39.2796  29.9065
 -51.1701  20.7146 -12.4891
 -24.2543 -39.5276  29.3515
 -51.0782  22.9095 -14.1458]
```

Using C++ Eigen libaray the result is following: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/classEigen_1_1JacobiRotation.html

```
 Result = [ 110.564    -7.77137   -0.308057
        0      87.445    -64.7691
        0           0     1.86159
        0           0           0
        0           0           0
        0           0           0
        0           0           0
        0           0           0]
```

Using matlab inbuilt function `qr` (`[~,R]=qr(A)`) gives me the following:

```
R = [  110.5645   -7.7714   -0.3081
     0  -87.4451         64.7691
     0         0        -1.8616
     0         0         0
     0         0         0
     0         0         0
     0         0         0
     0         0         0]
```

As it can be seen that first row result is same in C++ and matlab.
whereas the second and third row signs are not matching.
What is the correct solution or how can it be implemented in matlab?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generaly, eigen-vectors are only determined up to a sign,  and here you can see there is agreement up to the sign of the 2nd and 3rd row.

The reason for that is that multiplycation of any eigenvector by -1 does not change its status as an eigenvector. You can try using [eigenshuffle](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22885-eigenshuffle) from the File exchange if you are bothered by this.

Comment: Hi Thanks!!
If we rotate the a matrix which is equal to the eigenvalues, see the following [link] (http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/laff/alaff/chapter11-Jacobi-rotation.html).

I am able to determine the rotation, but only the first values is matching with C++ output. The other calculated values are always different.

Comment: is there a question here? did you understood my answer?